# Visual Studio freezes when I save then switch file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, freeze

Environment : Visual Studio 2010 v10.0.31118.1 SP1, Addins : jetBrain,DXCore,VisualSVN Windows 7 (up to date)

Since a long time Visual Studio is really slow, so I tried to see how to reproduce the problem and it's really simple : I add a letter to a file, save and then try to open an other file.

Then Visual Studio freezes for 10sec or more. if I just save or open a file there is no hang at all.

I looked at the processes with ProcEx.exe and I saw that devenv.exe has a lot of I/O.

So with ProcMon I tried to see what was going on, and I saw that visual studio opened every single file of my web site, and every file of the temporary asp.net files folder linked to my website.

So I looked at the stacktrace of every "ReadFile" operation and I get

```
0 fltmgr.sys fltmgr.sys + 0x2027 0xfffff880010ab027 C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys

1 fltmgr.sys fltmgr.sys + 0x48ca 0xfffff880010ad8ca C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys

2 fltmgr.sys fltmgr.sys + 0x222a3 0xfffff880010cb2a3 C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys

3 ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe + 0x373807 0xfffff80002dda807 C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

4 ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe + 0x369e84 0xfffff80002dd0e84 C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

5 ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe + 0x36ee4d 0xfffff80002dd5e4d C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

6 ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe + 0x375917 0xfffff80002ddc917 C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

7 ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe + 0x37f520 0xfffff80002de6520 C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

8 ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe + 0x6f993 0xfffff80002ad6993 C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

9 ntdll.dll ntdll.dll + 0x502aa 0x76f602aa C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

10 wow64.dll wow64.dll + 0x1bfe3 0x74c0bfe3 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll

11 wow64.dll wow64.dll + 0xcf87 0x74bfcf87 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll

12 wow64cpu.dll wow64cpu.dll + 0x276d 0x74b8276d C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll

13 wow64.dll wow64.dll + 0xd07e 0x74bfd07e C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll

14 wow64.dll wow64.dll + 0xc549 0x74bfc549 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll

15 ntdll.dll ntdll.dll + 0x7c367 0x76f8c367 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

16 ntdll.dll ntdll.dll + 0x32e2e 0x76f42e2e C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

17 ntdll.dll ntdll.dll + 0x20056 0x77110056 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll

18 KERNELBASE.dll KERNELBASE.dll + 0x1b616 0x750bb616 C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll

19 kernel32.dll kernel32.dll + 0x12345 0x74d82345 C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll

20 cslangsvc.dll TypeReference_Release + 0x36e86 0x535fbe8b C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

21 cslangsvc.dll TypeReference_Release + 0x36ed9 0x535fbede C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

22 cslangsvc.dll LangService_IsPrimaryThread + 0x2167 0x5357633b C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

23 cslangsvc.dll BaseNode_GetBaseOffset + 0x3f1c 0x536a8311 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

24 cslangsvc.dll BaseNode_GetBaseOffset + 0x39c6 0x536a7dbb C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

25 cslangsvc.dll cslangsvc.dll + 0xedd0 0x534fedd0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

26 cslangsvc.dll LexData_FindFirstPrecedingNonWhiteChar + 0x1a5a 0x5369b229 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

27 cslangsvc.dll cslangsvc.dll + 0x71efc 0x53561efc C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

28 cslangsvc.dll cslangsvc.dll + 0x71df3 0x53561df3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

29 cslangsvc.dll cslangsvc.dll + 0x72077 0x53562077 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

30 cslangsvc.dll UsingDirectiveNode_GetName + 0x603c2 0x5366428d C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\VCSPackages\cslangsvc.dll

31 kernel32.dll kernel32.dll + 0x13677 0x74d83677 C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll

32 ntdll.dll ntdll.dll + 0x39d42 0x77129d42 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll

33 ntdll.dll ntdll.dll + 0x39d15 0x77129d15 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
```

So do you have any guess ?

Thanks

Comment: Your .pdbs aren't good enough.  Disable the add-ins one by one.

Comment: @Hans Passant : What do you mean by "you .pdbs" aren't good enough ? I'll try to uninstall devexpress. (since I can't disableit, I'll try as a last hope to uninstall visualSVN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution : run CCleaner ! it seems that Visual Studio uses a lot the temp folder, and avast antivirus is scanning it every time you open/save a file.

So I couldn't had a filter in avast for the temp folder, so I preferred emptying it.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider downloading [the Visual Studio 2010 Diagnostic Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e8649e35-26b1-4e73-b427-c2886a0705f4/) and sending the results to Microsoft. The tool will collect a variety of performance information that will help the Visual Studio team come up with a solution (if it's an issue with the core product).